# How to determine if app is written with mobile web frameworks?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch, platform-agnostic

I'm doing market research of the competition and would like to know whether they have written their apps native or not.

Comment: Interesting question. Contact the developer and ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both APK and IPA files are merely zip files that follow certain conventions.  You can view the files inside by unarchiving them, it should be easy to identify files relating to frameworks like PhoneGap.  You can obtain the IPA for an iOS application by dragging it out of iTunes.

Comment: How does a Phonegap directory structure looks like?

Comment: Why don't you download it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Pull the apk from the device and use unzip. If you end up with a bunch of .js/.html files then it's mainly web tech.

```
adb -d shell pm list packages -f
```

This command will list all packages and there storage location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a foolproof way, but some warning signs I've noticed for these types of apps:

- Using the back button to go back doesn't cause an Activity switch animation to happen, it just refreshes the screen to the previous page
- Sometimes, the back button simply quits the app.
- Various UI elements look like the iPhone instead of Android. Particularly if there are back arrows in the upper left corner, or a spinner that looks like a mechanical odometer.
- Look at the package name. I have seen them named something like com.sillycompany.iphone when it is an Android app.

EDIT: I realize after reading your question tags you may not mean just Android apps. All my answers only pertain to my experience with Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Buy/download their app and play around with it.  You can usually get a feel of whether it is written in HTML & js or whether it is native by the look and feel of the controls (buttons switches, textfields, textviews, etc.).  If you're still having a hard time you can always pop open the .ipa and take a look at the resources packaged with the app.  If you find any html or js files then it's probably a web app.  You can also look at the binary of the app with a hex editor (you won't be able to see the source code but it should still give you an idea.

Answer (score -2):

If by mobile web framework you mean things like PhoneGap, then, technically speaking, you shouldn't be able to tell, as PhoneGap works within the IDE of the native dev environment and you end up with native code.

Comment: PhoneGap generates JS/HTML loaders. The html/js files are copied unmodified as assets. Titanium does a conversion.

Comment: PhoneGap runs inside a WebView and any direct integrations with the native OS is done via Cordova/PhoneGap plugins. As a result, most Cordova/PhoneGap apps look and feel slightly different from an app written in Java/Kotlin or even a Xamarin.Android app.